# Idiom for a solution which is better but not without the cost

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

I'm looking for an idiom (or phrase) to indicate that despite something, specifically a solution, is better than previous ones and with more features, it is not without cost and some barrier.

> E.g. However, the new solution is much better than the previous ones, ***this is not without overhead costs***.

One alternative for highlighted sentence may be "*this is not the silver bullet*", but it's not perfect for my case. Is there any alternative?

Comment: There's a ***trade-off***? ***caveat***? ***catch***?

Comment: "there is a price to pay for the gain".

Comment: "this solution is better, but more expensive."

Comment: 'You get what you pay for' is a related fixed expression.

Comment: Not without its limitations.

Answer (score 4):

To use a common idiom, it's better but ***comes at a price***.

TFD (idioms):

> **[come at a price](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/come+at+a+price)**
>   to include disadvantages in order to get what you want
>
> The company's success was made possible by the country's
>   rulers, but their support *comes at a price*.
>
> **Usage notes**: sometimes
>   used without come: Following the recommendation would have increased
>   teamwork, but *at a price*.
>
> Cambridge Dictionary of American Idioms Copyright © Cambridge
>   University Press 2003. Reproduced with permission.

Answer (score 1):

> This new solution is much better than the previous ones, but **there's a trade-off**.

***Trade-off*** — [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/trade-off)

> a situation in which you accept something bad in order to have something good:
>   For some car buyers, lack of space is an acceptable trade-off for a sporty design

Usage examples:

> Windows OS updates get simpler -- but there's a trade-off [[1]](http://searchenterprisedesktop.techtarget.com/news/450303044/Windows-OS-updates-get-simpler-but-theres-a-trade-off)
>   Plants help slow warming – but there's a trade-off [[2]](https://www.newscientist.com/article/dn23451-plants-help-slow-warming-but-theres-a-trade-off/)

Answer (score 1):

### "You get what you pay for"

This popular idiom is often used as a rebuke for an excessively cheap purchase (see [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/you%20get%20what%20you%20pay%20for)). However it could work here as a simple way of saying that this is the better solution, and therefore will cost a little more.

From [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/you_get_what_you_pay_for):

> Sometimes used with the opposite nuance, meaning that because something is expensive, it is thus high quality – “This luxury car is awesome!” “Yeah, you really get what you pay for.”

Answer (score 0):

> This new solution is much better than the previous ones, but **wait, there's a catch**.

***What's the catch?*** — [TFD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/What's+the+catch%3F)

> (slang) What is the **drawback**?; It sounds good, but are there any hidden problems?
>   *"Sounds too good to be true. What's the catch?"*
>   *"This looks like a good deal. What's the catch?"*

Comment: The cost, here, is not necessarily a problem. But it made the solution incomplete.